# How to cluster an 1-D array by K-means or any other algorithm using scikit-learn?

Tags: clustering, python, k-means, scikit-learn, numpy

I have an one dimensional toy array X.

I want to cluster the data into some numbers of clusters.But when I try to fit my data in scikit-learn K-Means function it shows

> ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=3

I think K-Means should work fine for 1-D data though it is not an efficient way to cluster 1-D data.So why it is not working?Are there some other scikit-learn implemented algorithms for clustering of 1-Dimensional data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am speculating: it sounds like you are trying to cluster the transpose of your array. so it thinks there is a single - very high dimensional sample. Try to see if that is the case and if so, transpose it.

Comment: Thanks man.I was just transposing the 1-D data.But I forgot transpose of  Numpy array is the array itself.